# xhr in chrome extension

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have created a small extension that requires to communicate with php script on the server side for mysql activities.

The code used for php connectivity works when used from a normal webpage
when i try to access it from a chrome extension, i aint sure if it is even getting called.

CODE:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var link = document.getElementById('signup_submit').submit();
// onClick's logic below:
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
alert('jksd');
    window.onload = function() {
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest;
var url = "http://localhost/browserExtension/chrome%20extensions/register.php";
var username = document.getElementById('usrname').value;
var dispname = document.getElementById('name').value;
var password = document.getElementById('passwd').value;
  var params = "usrname=" + username + "&name=" + dispname + "&passwd=" + password;
XHR.open("GET", url, true);
XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (4 == this.readyState) {
    var status = this.status;
    if (400 > status) {
      var responseText = this.responseText;
      if (responseText) {
        //document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = responseText;
      alert(responseText);
      }
  }
}
 };
 XHR.send(params);
 }




});
 });
```

Comment: it's be trivial to check the server's access logs to see if there's a hit coming in.

Comment: the hit did not occur.
nt sure of the reason.

Comment: Did you add `"http://localhost/"` to the `permissions` section of your manifest?

Comment: yes. i added localhost.